# c# split with some delimeters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like "1392/02/10 22:30:15", how can I separate each number in a variable with split? my code is in the following:

```
 string str1="1392/02/10 22:30:15";
 string[] str2 = str1.Split(new char[] { '/', ':',' '});
```

I got 1392, 02 and 10  but to get 22 by

```
  int hour = int.Parse(str2[3]);
```

make an execption with this title:"Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: It seems you are using DateTime values as a string. But if you keep them as the correct datatype, you don't need to split them to get the date/time parts.

Comment: Why are you splitting instead of *parsing* the date string into an actual DateTime and retrieving the value?

Comment: BTW, no repro. `int.Parse(str2[3]);` works without throwing anything with *this* input string.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]; this code doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: this code Work correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make much more sense if you'd just parse the date as a `DateTime`:

```
string str1 = "1392/02/10 22:30:15";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(str1, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you are not sure about the validness of your input, you can use `TryParseExact`:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str1, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime d))
{
    // the date is valid, use it
}
```

Your current code works, but is quite error prone. You better rely on pieces of the framework that automate this task. One problem with your code could be an extra space, a tab instead of a space, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately my problem does not solve, I got an exception that "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

Comment: Did you use that exact code for that exact date time string?

Comment: I used asp MVC and check local window when running  datetimestring shows correct but on that line make an exception

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: I write a function that get str1 something that you defined it in your example then I use your code in body function and return the result but it made the exception.

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: I am not sure that get you perfectly but the string is datetimestring and "1396/02/13  13:01:53"

Comment: Are you sure it is? There are no strange characters in it? Where do you get that string from?

Comment: I check its value from local window

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Finally I could solve my problem with all your help. I think you are right and I made one more space between date and time in datetime string.

Answer (score 5):

I'd parse the date

```
string input = "1392/02/10 22:30:15";
string format = "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int hour = result.Hour;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/489Ev3

Comment: That's the correct approach. The original code *doesn't* have any problem though, so the OP probably posted the wrong snippet

Comment: @fubo Thank you very much for your help, but I have another problem now that give me an exception on datetime result line that "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

Comment: I used asp MVC and check local window when running  datetimestring shows correct but on that line make an exception